# Unable to set a flag to an email

Tags: imap

I have a mail that I cannot mark as seen or deleted from my inbox.  (I don't know how I managed to have it…)  If it helps, the server is a Zimbra instance.

I tried to set the flags by hand, to be sure to catch any error message.  So `openssl s_client …`, `LOGIN` command, and then:

```
. SELECT INBOX
* 11 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UNSEEN 8] mailbox contains unseen messages
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs are valid for this mailbox
* OK [UIDNEXT 220360] next expected UID is 220360
* FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $MDNSent Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk Junk JunkRecorded NonJunk NotJunk)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $MDNSent Forwarded \*)] junk-related flags are not permanent
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 425603] modseq tracked on this mailbox
. OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
```

Very well.  I'm in `READ-WRITE` mode.  I check with another mail to be sure all is OK:

```
. FETCH 7 FLAGS
* 7 FETCH (FLAGS ())
. OK FETCH completed

. STORE 7 +FLAGS \Seen
* 7 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
. OK STORE completed
```

Super! I marked this one as seen.  But for the next one, with the same command, the `\Seen` flag is not set even if command succeeded:

```
. FETCH 8 FLAGS
* 8 FETCH (FLAGS ())
. OK FETCH completed

. STORE 8 +FLAGS \Seen
* 8 FETCH (FLAGS ())
. OK STORE completed
```

The same for the `\Deleted` flag.  Is there a normal situation where, in `READ-WRITE` mode, I cannot put a flag on a mail?  Or any test to check if something is wrong with my mailbox/mail?

*EDIT*, after arnt's suggestion:

I tried to copy this mail in another mailbox.  The message is well copied, with another UID, is readable, and **keeps the flags the former mail should have**: for example, it has the `\Deleted` flag set when I select the mailbox (but it is not expunged, so I still can check that the copy succeeded).

```
. COPY 8 "TestMB"
. OK [COPYUID 411900 220324 220409] COPY completed

. SELECT "TextMB"
* 1 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 411900] UIDs are valid for this mailbox
* OK [UIDNEXT 220410] next expected UID is 220410
* FLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $MDNSent Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk Junk JunkRecorded NonJunk NotJunk)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $MDNSent Forwarded \*)] junk-related flags are not permanent
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 425749] modseq tracked on this mailbox
. OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed

. FETCH 1:* (FLAGS UID BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)])
* 1 FETCH (UID 220409 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {63}
Subject: Enligne_[...]

 FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen))
. OK FETCH completed
```

Comment: This looks like a server bug ad/or back end database issue.  Can you read the message?  Get its body?

Comment: Since you ask about a way to test: Copy the message to the same mailbox and try again for the cloned message, e.g. `. copy 8 inbox`. To another mailbox and try there. All copies should behave in the same way.

Comment: @Max Sure I can read it, either with a `. FETCH 8 BODY[TEXT]` for example, or also from my thunderbird connected to the same mailbox.

Comment: Thanks, @arnt.  I tested and put some details in the question.  I also suspect a server bug / database issue on that particular mail, as the copy behaves exactly as expected.  The flags effectively exist on the mail, even if they are not displayed or read.

Comment: This behaviour is not legal IMAP, and sounds like something you'll want to report to the server vendor.

Comment: OK.  It was a bug.  The mail disappeared this weekend from my inbox and ended up in the trash.